Why did Jesus turn water into wine in John 2:1-11?
2 On the third day a wedding took place at Cana in Galilee. Jesus’ mother was there, 2 and Jesus and his disciples had also been invited to the wedding. 3 When the wine was gone, Jesus’ mother said to him, “They have no more wine.”
4 “Woman, why do you involve me?” Jesus replied. “My hour has not yet come.”
5 His mother said to the servants, “Do whatever he tells you.”
6 Nearby stood six stone water jars, the kind used by the Jews for ceremonial washing, each holding from twenty to thirty gallons.
7 Jesus said to the servants, “Fill the jars with water”; so they filled them to the brim.
8 Then he told them, “Now draw some out and take it to the master of the banquet.”
They did so, 9 and the master of the banquet tasted the water that had been turned into wine. He did not realize where it had come from, though the servants who had drawn the water knew. Then he called the bridegroom aside 10 and said, “Everyone brings out the choice wine first and then the cheaper wine after the guests have had too much to drink; but you have saved the best till now.”
11 What Jesus did here in Cana of Galilee was the first of the signs through which he revealed his glory; and his disciples believed in him.

The wine represents blood; the blood of Christ, and we know according to 1 John 5:7 that the Water, the Blood, and the Spirit testify that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

We are washed (water) by the blood (wine) of Christ. His first miracle at the wedding at Cana was a foreshadow of his ultimate miracle, our redemption by the water and blood (wine) of his death on the cross.

The whole context of John's gospel needs to be considered. Then the buildup to the event, covering chapters one two and three. The whole of this conveys spiritual doctrine and requires a full and spiritual explanation which would take an entire book to convey. The short answer is - because they had no wine.

Amazing short-answer, Nigel J.

@NigelJ – they had no wine, representing not having atoning blood for their sins, which Christ provides through his miracle.

@OneGodOneLord Absolutely not. The event (and its context) are a matter of the baptism of repentance and union with Christ through regeneration.

@NigelJ – Are you blind? That's the very point I was making. Union with Christ through the regenerative washing away of sin by the atoning blood of the Word. (1 John 5:7 "Water, Blood, Spirit; these agree")

@OneGodOneLord No, I am not blind and no, I cannot see that that is what you stated. No further comment, thank you.

@NigelJ – I pray that you find peace!

Based on scripture I'd like to note a few things:

John 2:11 - This beginning of His signs Jesus did in Cana of
Galilee, and revealed His glory; and His disciples believed in Him.


It revealed His glory
His disciples believed


John 2:3 - When the wine ran out, the mother of Jesus *said to Him,
“They have no wine.”


Jesus responded to a practical need

If there had been no need, then there would have been no reason for Jesus to act.
It is known that running out of wine would have been a major social embarrassment for the hosts. Jesus' intervention spared the host from this.
All 3 of these reason would be why Jesus turned the water into wine.

There's a much deeper message underneath the miraculous story here, namely the Gospel of atonement in Christ.

Wine represents his shed blood and that is important (Matthew 26:26-28). That He created wine in abundance (likely more than they could drink that night) may represent the abundance of the salvation He provides to the multitudes of believers through His blood.
Something else to consider; the wine was a practical necessity. This was at a wedding and a fitting event for Christ to start His ministry.  The importance of human marriage as a picture of Christ and the Church was not known at that time.  We learn in Ephesians of this mystery, that the Church is the bride of Christ. Mysteries were always determined from the beginning but the full understanding was not revealed until by revelation.  This defines our relationship with Christ.
Ephesians 5:22-32 (LSB)


Wives, be subject to your own husbands, as to the Lord. 23. For the husband is the head of the wife, as Christ also is the head of the church, He Himself being the Savior of the body. 24. But as the church is subject to Christ, so also the wives ought to be to their husbands in everything. 25. Husbands, love your wives, just as Christ also loved the church and gave Himself up for her, 26. so that He might sanctify her, having cleansed her by the washing of water with the word, 27. that He might present to Himself the church in all her glory, having no spot or wrinkle or any such thing, but that she would be holy and blameless. 28. So husbands ought also to love their own wives as their own bodies. He who loves his own wife loves himself; 29. for no one ever hated his own flesh, but nourishes and cherishes it, just as Christ also does the church, 30. because we are members of His body. 31. For this reason a man shall leave his father and mother and be joined to his wife, and the two shall become one flesh. 32.This mystery is great, but I am speaking with reference to Christ and the church. 33. Nevertheless, each individual among you also is to love his own wife even as himself, and the wife must see to it that she respects her husband.


It could be that both factors are important.

One gallon equals 3.8 liters. Jesus turned water in six jars containing 30 gallons each, that is he made almost 684 liters of wine . We will  never know how many people attended the wedding and how much  the shortage was.  We also don't know if there was leftover wine after all guests had had their tummy full. ( Well, a crafty antique seller could offer you a small bottle of clay with old wine,claiming that he had procured it from an ancient Church in Cana , which had put the left- over miraculous wine on auction ! )
Verse 3 says that the ' wine was gone ' . It could mean different things. Wine making is a delicate process. Too much of water and too little of sugar added to the grapes can produce vinegar. The mix, while fermenting,  could also get infested  with rival fungus, if not stored in hygienic condition. Such things may have come to light only when the barrels were opened before serving, leaving no scope for outsourcing of wine to cover the shortage. Anyway, getting short of wine during the banquet is in deed  a prestige issue for the host.
..
It looks like that even the master of the banquet  had not been told of the shortage,given the way he praises the new wine (Verse 10) .Jesus , on the request of the Blessed Mother,intervened at the right time to save the family from disgrace. He would not make wine from air, as if in act of magic. Water was the only liquid available to the scale of 700 liters. So, he used water as the base.
Now, that is the straightforward answer. Jesus never mentioned the incident thereafter, unlike the multiplication of bread he would subsequently refer to for the sake of understanding of his disciples( Mk 18:19-21).
